# How do I close the panel when clicked on 'x' button and click on the screen using angularjs?(new to angular)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Here is my HTML code for my button

```
  <button class="btn btn-outlined  " ng-click="vm.showCommentBox1()">Notify All</button>
    <div class="comment-box custom saveAll" ng-if=""><div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" ng-click="comment=true" title="Close comment box"><span aria-hidden="true">Ã—</span>
                      </button>
                    <h3 class="panel-title blue-30">Comment</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control bg-white" ng-model=""
                          placeholder="Add your description"></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

so when i click the 'x' button the panel should get closed

Comment: So you click on the button and it set `$scope.comment` to `true`. What now?

Comment: i want to close the panel....which the button is referring to@AlonEitan

Comment: So set it to `false` maybe? I mean, try to think about it for a moment - How do you expect to get help if you don't add any context to you question? Which "panel"? What exactly is "close the panel"? Do  you really believe we can see your code, or are we supposed to guess what it look like?

Comment: Thank you...i have updated the code....@AlonEitan

Comment: `<div class="panel panel-default" ng-if="!comment">` OR `<div class="panel panel-default" ng-show="!comment">` OR `<div class="panel panel-default" ng-hide="comment">` (since clicking on the close button set `comment` to `true`)

Comment: do it with css, when close class clicked hide the pannel

Comment: @Jagadeesh No need - When you use `ngShow` / `ngHide` angular remove/add `ng-hide` class from/to the element (Respectively), based on the expression, and this class is simply `.ng-hide {display: none;}` - So angular already handle the css aspect

Comment: Thank you.....it works(i can close the panel on click).....but what if i need to again get the same panel onclick of the Notify All button as i have updated in the code....@AlonEitan

Comment: @HKI345 Will this help you to better understand? https://jsfiddle.net/6pwk0z9f/2/

Comment: @AlonEitan....Thank you it helped..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `ng-if="comment===true"` on the desired element in order to remove the element when you have set comment to true by pressing to 'x' button.

Comment: Thank you..can you be bit explanatory @Icehorn